# Jenkins: hudson.security.AccessDeniedException2: anonymous is missing the Overall/Read permission

Tags: windows, jenkins, tomcat7

I get the following error after I have deployed the Jenkins WAR file version 1.643 or above. I downloaded it from the permanent link to the latest WAR file.

I deployed this on Tomcat 7 Windows 7 OS. After that I made a few changes to the security and added few roles. I must have not given any permissions to the anonymous user and now get this error:
**hudson.security.AccessDeniedException2: anonymous is missing the Overall/Read permission**

I have referred to other links on this site about finding the config.xml file in the Jenkins Home directory and editing it. I cant find this file. Its not in the jenkins war file. I have searched all the folders as well after its exploded from WAR file to a folder in Tomcat.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I also tried to change my Tomcat directory to another installation of Tomcat. Deployed another version of Jenkins WAR file. Deleted all temp files, cookies but still see the same error? What in the world is wrong? How come I cant find this config.xml file in Jenkins directory?

Answer (score 0):

I found the config.xml file.

It was under C:\Users\username\.jenkins

I had to run a manual search in windows to find it. Hope this helps someone.